# SvelteKit can't find audio files running with node build

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have an API (located at `/src/routes/api/bell/+server.ts`), that returns a random audio file as a base64.
My Audio files are located at `/src/lib/audio` (I also tried `/src/lib/sever/audio`).

I'm using `raddirSync` and `readFileSync` from `fs` to read and return a random file.
In Code:

```
export const GET = (async () => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync('$lib/audio');
    const randomFile = files.at(Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length));

    const audioBase64 = fs.readFileSync('$lib/audio/' + randomFile, { encoding: 'base64' });

    return json(audioBase64);

}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

I'm now trying to deploy by using `adapter-node`.
Running `node build` and triggering the API throws

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '$lib/server/audio'`.

---

I tried:

- Changing location of the Audio files to: `/src/lib/sever/audio`. That way they at least seem to be included in the build at `.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/[name].mp3`
- Using vites `import.meta.glob`. With this I could get random Paths but I don't know how I could return the file without using `fs` again.
- Importing the Audio files with `import '[filename]?raw'` and turning them into base64. I didn't tried this one but I found threads about this and it seems not to work ether and doesn't fit for my case, where I may not know all files in the directory.

Does anyone know why fs doesn't work or how a 'vite only' solution would look like?

Answer (score 0):

### OLD ANSWER

Ok I think I found the solution.

While using `fs` on the client in vite is not allowed (logical), on the Server its possible (I thought this might be a problem, but just to get it out of the way, it isn't and vite even uses fs at some examples themselves).

But while building, vite adds a little hash to the files so `fs` can't find them.

I added my audio directory to my vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: '$lib/audio/[name][Extension]'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'm still not sure where exactly vite puts them now and how `fs` is handling the path, cause that is still changing, like with images which are located at `_app/immutable`. Guess there exists a mapping used in the background.

So if anyone knows more about a finished build, I'm still interested on that.

---

### UPDATE #1:


Didn't work, cause sveltekit overwrites it. Seems like it does this even if I add vite configurations in svelte.config.ts.
I now have a solution using vites `import.meta.glob`. Unfortunately I end up with a path that's not relative anymore.

The whole `/src/routes/api/bell/+server.ts`-file now:

```
import type {RequestHandler} from './$types';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {json} from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type {ImportGlobFunction} from "vite";
import * as path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

export const GET = (async () => {
    const audioFilePath: string[] = [];

    const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

    let audioFiles: Record<string, any> = {};
    audioFiles = import.meta.glob('$lib/audio/*', { eager: true});

    for (const path in audioFiles) {
        audioFilePath.push(path);
    }

    const randomPath: string | undefined = audioFilePath.at(Math.floor(
        Math.random() * audioFilePath.length));

    if (randomPath){
        const randomRootPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../client'+audioFiles[randomPath].default);
        const audioBase64 = fs.readFileSync(randomRootPath, { encoding: 'base64' });
        return json(audioBase64);
    }

    return json('No Audio found');
}) satisfies RequestHandler;
```

My Problem now: Vite and nodejs functions are not very compatible, also this method doesn't work on local dev-server anymore. This only works for my Prod-Docker.

So if anyone finds this: I'm still interested in a solution. There need to be a much easier way and I think I get something obvious wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue this is what worked for me.

I had my files in the `/src` directory but it seems SvelteKit wants you to put files like audio and images in the `/static` directory.

in your code you don't even have to refer to it like `/static/img/waveform.svg` you just go `/img/waveform.svg`

Comment: I'm not quite happy with that solution, because the static directory is normally not protected (of course not, because its made to serve assets that are public anyway).
But what if I'm planing to restrict access to my side, or give people the ability to upload their own audios? These should be protected.